# Java Logger entering() and exiting() methods

Tags: java, logging

I just started to use **Java Logger**. I tried to use its `entering()` and `exiting()` methods with hard coded string for class name and method. They both didn't work for me. Just no log entry for them. But other log statements within that methods were logged properly. My logger level is set to `CONFIG`. I have tried to set to `ALL` but still cannot see log entry from them.

I found for each entry, there already has a line with class name and method being logged. It seems these two methods are not necessary. But I am still want to know how to make them work for me.

**EDIT:**

My code followed: these entering() and exiting() are not create an entry in the log file

```
//class variables
private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MyClass.class.getName());
private static FileHandler logFileHandler = null;

//within the main() method
Logger thisLogger = Logger.getLogger("");
logFileHandler =  new FileHandler(logFileNameStr, false);
logFileHandler.setFormatter(new SimpleFormatter());
thisLogger.addHandler(logFileHandler);
thisLogger.setLevel(Level.CONFIG);
logger.log(Level.INFO, "Logfile Directory = " + logFileNameStr);


//within a constructor of MyClass
logger.entering("MyClass", "MyClass()");
....
logger.info(initMsg);
....
logger.exiting(this.getClass().getSimpleName(), "MyClass()");
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Entering, exiting, and throwing are logged at level FINER.  You'll have to set your logger to FINER or lower and set your FileHandler to FINER or lower.

```
thisLogger.addHandler(logFileHandler);
thisLogger.setLevel(Level.FINER);
logFileHandler.setLevel(Level.ALL);
```

As far as style goes, you should try creating a static final for class name because you'll use it as the [name of the logger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#getLogger-java.lang.String-) and reference it for [entering](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#entering-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), [exiting](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#exiting-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-), [throwing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#throwing-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.Throwable-), and [log precise](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/logging/Logger.html#logp-java.util.logging.Level-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-) tracing:

```
private static final String CLASS_NAME = MyClass.class.getName();
```

You always want to use a class literal to fetch the name (as above) because [`getClass().getName()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#getClass--) can return a subclass name which can falsify your tracing.

For method names don't include `()` in the name, just use the entering/exiting method that matches the number of arguments.

For constructor method names use `"<init>"` and for static init blocks use `"<clinit>"` as the method name since that is what would show up in a stacktrace.

Comment: Is it possible to change the level at the entering and exiting methods will be written? I want these logs to written if its INFO level or lower..

Comment: @Vishnu It is not supported by default.  There are workarounds but, comment section is not large enough to explain them.  Ask a new question if you want to explore those options.

Answer (score 2):

As @jmehrens said, these "convenience" methods are logged at finer and your Logger and Handler objects are likely configured at a much higher level by default.

Here are more convenient entering and exiting replacements for use within the logged method and which you can simply change the level on:

```
logger.finer("ENTRY"); // compare to .entering(MyClass.class.getName(),"MyMethodName")
...
logger.finer("RETURN"); // less typing than .exiting(CLASS_NAME,"MyMethodName")
```

Same output as entering and exiting as long as you're providing the real class and method name. Simple enough to change .finer to .info.

To handle the parameterized versions use .log:

```
logger.log(Level.FINER,"ENTRY {0}", param1);
...
logger.log(Level.FINER,"RETURN {0}", result);
```

I think the only place entering/exiting makes sense is when you're logging from the caller's side:

```
logger.entering(thing.getClass().getName(),"DoStuff");
thing.DoStuff();
logger.exiting(thing.getClass().getName(),"DoStuff");
```

You could do the same with logp have control over what level it logs at, but it is more verbose:

```
logger.logp(Level.FINER,thing.getClass().getName(),"DoStuff","ENTRY");
thing.DoStuff();
logger.logp(Level.FINER,thing.getClass().getName(),"DoStuff","RETURN");
```